# How to do a country specific search in google

Tags: google-search, google-ads-api, google-search-api

I want to do a search in google by a keyword. I can do it by the following:
    http://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&output=search&q=keyword
This search is returning the result according to my current country. I can change the result for a specific country by adding **site:country** with the keyword. But in that case Ads in the search result page are not showing. I want to see the country specific Ads as well while searching for a keyword. Can anyone please help me to do that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried playing with the `hl` parameter in the url? for example `hl=it` brings pages in italian, and `hl=es` in spanish

Comment: As per I know hl parameter is to select language. I am happy with english. I need to see which sites and ads are showing in US, UK, Australia or Canada for my selected keyword.

Comment: Google has different domains acc to countries https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Google_domains try using a domain that is local to that country